# Dropdown closes when passing height of containing element

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown that goes over the height of its containing element. When I mouse past the containing elements height the dropdown closes. Does anyone know how I could try and fix this?

http://dronework.com.au/

This is the ul's class before hover...

```
.wpjb-filters .wpjb-sub-filters {
display: none;
background: #9ecf32;
top: -18px;
position: relative;
z-index: 14;
padding-top: 2em !important;
padding-bottom: 1em !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

On hover...

```
@media (min-device-width: 1024px){
.wpjb-filters .wpjb-top-filter:hover .wpjb-sub-filters {
    display: block;
}
```

The issue is when you pass around about this point...

[image: Problem image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is indeed wordpress, I'm updating the question as I found the hover that makes it a display:block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that these `<div>`'s are overlapping with your menu list at that specified position.

`<div class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_overlay"></div>`

`<div class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll"></div>`

So I just changed their `z-index` to negative values and it seems working.

```
.et_pb_fullwidth_header_overlay{
    z-index: -3;
}

.et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll{
   z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This works! I think the theme leaves these in if certain options are enabled.

Comment: Glad ! It helped you :)